# Term for phobia of various groups

Tags: terminology

So I am **not** looking for 'Enochlophobia' or 'Agoraphobia' the fear of large crowds.

I am looking for a generic term (or is it collect noun?!) for phobia of various groups of people e.g. homophobia, Islamophobia, racism etc.

Comment: Are you looking for the word to describe someone who suffers from numerous phobias? In that case they would suffer from polyphobia and they would be polyphobic. Or manybe multiphobic?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no I am looking for fears of people-groups, not for a general collection of phobias

Answer (score 4):

These would all seem to come under the more generic term xenophobia:

> : fear and hatred of strangers or foreigners or of anything that is strange or foreign

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/xenophobia)

As they note, this extends the traditional "fear" meaning of phobia to include extreme dislike.

Comment: Good answer. Do you think it could apply to people who are fearful of women (i.e., fearful of women taking their jobs) or would there be another better term?

Comment: I think one could reasonably *define* it to include that, for example if writing about some of the “anti-feminist” groups that exist.

Comment: True. Although that would be a little too much like 'fight'n words' for what I am looking for. However you have given me a good starting point to begin digging through a thesaurus with. Thanks :D